# How do I express this SQL query in Scala and Quill using filter and groupBy?

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala

```sql
SELECT
    posts.id, posts.title, COUNT(clicks.id)
FROM
    posts LEFT OUTER JOIN clicks ON posts.id = clicks.post_id
WHERE
    posts.author_id = '269286af-3be5-4dad-8b17-96704742b9a5'
    AND posts.timestamp > current_timestamp - '2 week'::interval
GROUP BY
    posts.id
```

I tried this:

```scala
for {
    post <- Posts
        .leftJoin(Clicks).on((p, c) => p.id == c.postId)
        .map { case (post, _) => post }
        .filter(p => p.authorId == lift(userId) && p.isDeleted == lift(false))
    clickCount <- Clicks
        .groupBy(_.postId)
        .map { case (_, clicks) => clicks.size }
} yield ClickCount(post.id, post.title, clickCount)
```

but that gives me this error at compile time:

```
exception during macro expansion: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The monad composition can't be expressed using applicative joins. Faulty expression: 'p.id'. Free variables: 'List(p)'., Faulty expression: 'p.title'. Free variables: 'List(p)'.
```

### Update

Michal Pawlicki provided the missing pieces in his answer. Based on that, I arrived at this, which works as intended:

```scala
for {
    post <- Posts
    clickCount <- Clicks
        .leftJoin(_.postId == post.id)
        .filter(_ => post.authorId == lift(userId) && !post.isDeleted)
        .groupBy(_ => post.id)
        .map {
            case (_, rows) =>
                ClickCount(
                    post.id,
                    post.title,
                    rows.map { maybeClick =>
                        maybeClick.map(_.id)
                    }.size
                )
        }
} yield clickCount
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```scala
val q = quote {
  Posts
    .leftJoin(Clicks).on((p, c) => p.id == c.postId)
    .filter { case (p, _) => p.authorId == lift(userId) && p.isDeleted == false }
    .groupBy { case (post, _) => (post.id, post.title) }
    .map { case ((postId, postTitle), rows) =>
      ClickCount(postId, postTitle, rows.map(_._2.map(_.id)).size)
    }
}
```

results in:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.title, COUNT(c.id)
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN click c ON p.id = c.post_id
WHERE p.author_id = ? AND p.is_deleted = false
GROUP BY p.id, p.title
```

Full example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IOEWWgZ6QM62TVe0H3e1Rw

Comment: Amazing, thank you! That got me what I needed, and I've updated my post with the final solution. The innermost maps to get the count right are quite convoluted, so I need to think some more about how they map to the SQL.